# Monitor disk occupancy

Tags: mac-osx, monitoring, unix, shell, disk-space-utilization

The problem should be simple, but not so obvious to me.

I have a process that creates temporaries in a specified directory, **under MacOS X**. I need to find the **disk occupancy** of the process, if possible using a shell script.

My problem is that I cannot find an easy way from a `du -ahc` to get the directory size while a process is running, and monitoring it.

I'd settle even with just getting the **max** size, and not the size over time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: 'occupancy' is rather vague, could you explain?

Comment: The overall disk space occupied by all the files and directories in a given path.